# How to download files with Discord.Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I have a file "example.html" in my bot directory, I would like to make a button on my bot so that when I click it I download this document to my computer. How could I do this?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to directly download a file from a button in discord.
There are two ways I can think of that would accomplish the same (sort of).

#### 1. Host the file

you could host the file online and use a [link button](https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/message-components#button-object-button-styles). When clicking the button the user gets redirected to the given URL and they could download it from there.

#### 2. Attachment

Another way to do this would be sending the file as an attachment and the let the users download it directly from Discord. You would need to use the [AttachmentBuilder](https://discord.js.org/docs/packages/discord.js/14.14.1/AttachmentBuilder:Class) class to do this.